# How can I add ImageButtons to ScrollView?

Tags: android

If I try to add *ImageButton* to layout,it doesn't seems anything.Anyone can help me? I tried everything, but it doesn't work.
Here is code:
.xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/categories_action"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cat_iv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/categories_first_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

> the background is 1080x1920 image

Comment: what you want to do ? place button above scrollview ?

Comment: I would recommend to place your imageButton inside RelativeLayout

Comment: show your whole xml layout with question

Comment: Not working! Same problem..

Answer (score 0):

ImageButton can not be shown because your ScrollView located above ImageButton.
You need to place ImageButton in ScrollView or below ScrollView.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!! But how can I do, that my buttons be scrollable?

Comment: If you need to make buttons scrollable, you need to put button in scrollview. You can scroll when only content view has higher height than scrollview height.

Comment: use nested scroll view

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/imageButton"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:layout_above="@+id/cat_iv1"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/categories_action"/>

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cat_iv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/categories_first_background" />    

    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```